# Does a BLE device reads advertising packets when not scanning? (autoconnect)

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I read in some places that advertising packets are sent to every one in the distance range. However, should the other device be scanning to receive them or it will receive it anyways?

The problem: 
let's say I'm establishing a piconet between 5 or 6 BLE devices. At some point I have some connections between the slaves and one master. Then if one of the devices get removed/shut off for a few days I would like it to reconnect back to the network as soon as turned on.

I read about the autoconnect feature but it seems when you set it true, the device creates a background scanning which is actually slower (in frequency) than the manual scanning. This makes me conclude that for the autoConnect to work the device which is being turned on again needs to advertise again, right? Therefore, if autoconnect really runs a slow scan on background so it seems to me that you can never receive the adv packets instantly unless you're scanning somehow. Does that make sense?

If so, is there any way around it? I mean, detect the device that is comming back to the range instantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is "Instant". You are talking about radio protocols with delays, timeouts, retransmits, jamming, etc.  There are always delays.  The important thing is what you consider acceptable for your application.

A radio transceiver is either receiving, sleeping or transmitting, on one given channel at a time. Transmitting and receiving implies power consumption.

When a Central is idle (not handling any connection at all), all it has to do is scanning. It can do it full time (even if spec says this should be duty cycled).  You can expect to actually receive an advertising packet from peer Peripheral the first time it is transmitted.

When a Central is maintaining a connection to multiple peripherals, its transceiver time is shared between all the connections to maintain. Background scanning is considered low priority, and takes some of the remaining transceiver time.  Then an advertising Peripheral may send its ADV packet while Central is not listening.

Here comes statistical magic:

Spec says interval between two advertising events must be augmented with a (pseudo-)random delay.  This ensures Central (scanner) and Peripheral (advertiser) will manage to see each other at some point in time. Without this random delay, their timing allocations could become harmonic, but out of phase, and it could happen they never see each other.

Depending on the parameters used on Central and Peripheral (advInterval, advDelay, scanWindow, scanInterval) and radio link quality, you can compute the probability to be able to reach a node after a given time.  This is left as an exercise to the reader... :)

In the end, the question you should ask yourself looks like "is it acceptable my Peripheral is reconnected to my Central after 300 ms in 95% of cases" ?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yea, actually I was a bit exaggerated when saying instantly. The point is because I read somewhere that this background scanning (when autoConnect = 1) has an interval around 1s. That's too long for me, but 300ms would be fine. Is it possible to increase the autoConnect scan frequency (give it a little bit higher priority)?

Comment: It depends on your device and its implementation. Spec-defined scanning periods are "Recommended values". Limits may or may not be enforced by your manufacturer firmware / stack.

Comment: I see. I was also thinking about this mismatch possibility when scanning. I could set the advertiser to continously advertise so there's not much chance of the master not seeing the advertising on its time window. However it seems the minimum advertise interval is 20ms. Do you reckon this is also device/stack dependent or probably I won't be able to go lower than 20ms?

Comment: For reconnection to a known device, there is a "High Duty Cycle Directed Advertising" (See 6.B.4.4.2.4.2) where Peripheral must use an interval less than 3.75ms, but this may last no more than 1.28s. Then device shall fallback to lower duty cycled undirected advertising.